# не работает метод "DELETE"

Tags: android

Столкнулся вот с такой незадачей: при отладке приложения шлю `DELETE` запрос на сервер (сервер мой соответственно могу видеть входящие запросы), так вот на 4.2 Android'e все работает нормально и ответ 204, но вот на android'e 5 ответ 500 (ошибка сервера). Повторюсь что код один и тот же . По сути отправляется только http адрес, без тела. Проверял, так же, в Postman - ответ 204. Короче ничего не понимаю. Может кто сталкивался. Да кстати проявилась ошибка после обновления ОС. И все остальные методы (put, get, post) работают нормально.Менял в коде метод на "GET" -  работает.

Comment: Используете Retrofit ?

Comment: Нет. Использую HttpUrlConnection  для сетевого запроса. Устанавливаю метод "DELETE". Собственно и все.